# Ocean Travel By Sail

Tags: sea-travel, sailing

When looking to get into sailing, what is a good (or a few good) sailboat options for someone who would probably have a trip of 2 weeks max? Probably a crew of around 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Join an experienced captain and his crew. Ocean sailing is not for new sailors. If you have to ask here you do not have enough experience.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying, but I'm not going to be sailing across the ocean. Just weekend coastal sailing. I probably should post this question in a sailboat enthusiast forum though to get a real answer.

Comment: Unless you could specify where and when you are going to sail, this site is not suitable and even when you do, it is likely to not get the answer you need. Even on quiet lakes sudden storms can sink boats. Oceans, even the coastal waters, are worse for safety.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for your answer. It would be a long while before I am able to get into sailing anyway, I am just gathering information and such. I'll check more sailing specific forums. You can close this question. Thanks!

Comment: Even more reason to join others in sailing, learning it is much more important than which boat.